# fade out load then fade in does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

so guys i have a list of bunch of stuff that a user can do it loads content of other pages into a div what happens is that the current content of the div flashes (fades out then in again) then the new content appear what i want to do is make the fadein animation wait until the content is ready to load then fade in the div here is the jquery code iam currently using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#History").click(function(){
        $('#Display').fadeOut("fast").load("History.php").fadeIn("fast");
    });
    $("#Items").click(function(){
        $('#Display').fadeOut("fast").load("SellerItems.php").fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two things**: 1, you need to hide the div before loading, and 2, fade in when it’s ready.

I would animate the opacity here instead of using `fadeIn` for better control:

```
$("#History").click(function(){
    $('#Display').css('opacity', 0).load("History.php", function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a bunch dude this works perfectly the other ones flashes too if anyone is going to use this

Answer (score 3):

Use the [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) parameter that comes with both `fadeOut()` and `load()` methods. They will be called when the fade out is complete and the AJAX process is complete, respectively:

```
$("#History").click(function(){
    $('#Display').fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).load("History.php", function(){
            $(this).fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be even more effective to load the content while the fadeOut is being performed using a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The load method supports callbacks.
For example:

```
$('#Display').load("SellerItems.php", function() {
   $(this).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function takes a callback that runs when the operation is complete, like:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

So what you should do is add the callbacks to your code:

```
$("#History").click(function () {
  $('#Display').load("History.php", function () {
    $(this).fadeIn("fast");
  });
});
```